# Read earth coordinates from an excel file, and draw markers in a map

Tags: excel

I have an excell file with a column with earth coordinates inside Spain.I want to create a script or application that reads that data, and put a marker in a map of Spain, how can I generate those markers in a map? I don't need details, but just abstract information.

Should I create a macro maybe? Should I use google maps?

Comment: Are you willing to use .net and take advantage of google map api to display the results or do you want it inside of excel?

Comment: @PortlandRunner yes, if you think that is the best way to get what I want. By the way, Im a web programmer (PHP, HTML, jQuery, CSS..)

Comment: Just found this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kfv-NKS7hfI) that may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Since your tag is Excel, here is an example:

[image: SO19297635 example]

This is a Scatter chart with a Picture Fill.

Comment: thanks, but are you using google maps? if not, what are you using?